# Can I write this query more elegantly with AREL/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel

Can I write this query shorter and/or more elegantly using the AREL/ActiveRecord API?

```
Foo.where("(bar is not null and bar != '') or (baz is not null and baz !='')")
```

Comment: Probably not. Raw SQL is often more concise. It is also sometimes tied directly to a particular DBM, which is where an ORM starts to shine, because they are less tightly coupled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do an `OR` operator with Arel directly but the syntax isn't hugely pretty and can get a bit hard to read. Here is what it would look like in arel:

```
foo  = Foo.arel_table
Foo.where(foo[:bar].not_eq(nil).and(foo[:bar].not_eq('')).or(foo[:baz].not_eq(nil).and(foo[:baz].not_eq(''))))
```

I'd suggest looking at the squeel gem. It gives you access to more arel functionality in active record. Your query would like like:

```
Foo.where{(bar.not_eq nil) & (bar.not_eq '') | (baz.not_eq nil) & (baz.not_eq nil)}
```

Here is the link for more info: http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/

There are a few different ways you can write that in squeel, it supports a few different syntax styles so if you don't liked the one above there are alternatives.

Comment: Seems squeel hasn't been updated in over 3 years. Looks like the successor is now: https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel They also have documentation if you need to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

The sane way to deal with this (if you have the rights do do this of course on the database) is to disallow empty string values in the database. Then you can do Foo.where(:bar => nil). I use attribute_normalizer for this, and also to format values correctly.

https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer

A quick search also reveals nilify blanks, but I haven't tried that because attribute normalizer already provides that functionality for me.

https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks

The resulting sql for the search you want if you have a well kept database (either null or empty string values for empty fields is probably as short as it gets. (I prefer empty strings myself).

Comment: yep, that would be ideal, but not a maintainable solution in this case